# Why does the height of the sidebar changes when the browser is minimized?

Tags: html, css

I've made the sibebar height 202% to be equal to the two articles because the margin between the two articles messes up the equal alignment. But why is it that when i minimize the browser, the height of the sidebar changes a little bit, and becomes shorter? If i align it manually again to equal the sidebar, when i expand the browser to full size, the height is now too long. Why is this happening?

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


header {

background-color:lightgray;
height:150px;
color:black;
text-align:;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
font-size:50px;
font-family:OCR A Stf, monospace;


}

header a {

    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;


}

nav {

    background-color:darkblue;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;


}

nav a {

    text-decoration:none;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;

}



article {
    background-color:white;
    height:100%;
    padding:15px;
    overflow:;
    width:80%;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}


article h2 {

    padding-bottom:30px;
    color:black;

}




footer {

    background-color:lightgray;
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:15px;   
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;


}


.sidebar {

  padding:15px;
  width:18%;
  height:200%;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid lightgray;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float:right;


}


@media (max-width:700px) {

        .sidebar, .pics, .pics2 {

            width:100%;

        }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<head>

<title>No Internet</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css for new wc3.css"/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>



<body>



<header> 
<a href="new-wc3.html">Cities of the world</a>
 </header>



<nav>

<a href="new york page.html">New York City</a>
<a href="#2">Los Angeles</a>


</nav>


<section style="background-color:#f1f1f1; padding:30px; overflow:hidden">



<aside class="sidebar">

<p>This should be a sidebar</p>

</aside>




<article class="pics">

 <h2>Please select a city.</h2>

</article>



<article class="pics2">

 <h2>Please select a city.</h2>

</article>


</section>




<footer>

<p>Copyright &copy; 2020, Cities of the World</p>

</footer>



</body>
```

Comment: Not working. It's even worse that way. It's more difficult to adjust the sidebar to be equal size as the neighboring article element, and when i minimize the browser, the height of the sidebar is much larger than it was when it was in percentage. Why is the height changing?

Comment: But both elements inside the section are floating, which means their height is relative to the viewport. That's why 100% height of either one of them makes the element 100% of the viewport. The margins of the two articles makes the sidebar aligned a little bit off, so i had to adjust it with the extra 2%. But what i don't get is, why is it that when i minimize the browser, the height of the sidebar shrinks? There must be some property in play here.

Comment: I want to know WHY does the height of the sidebar shrink when i minimize the browser. That is literally my question.

Comment: How can you tell what's happening with the sidebar when the browser is minimized?

Comment: What do you mean? When the browser is fully opened, the sidebar is aligned with the other elements, when i minimize the browser, the height of the sidebar slightly shrinks. If i increase it, when i maximize my browser, it is too large now. I can probably find a way to align them, but i want to know why is it shrinking in the first place?

Comment: Are you using EXACTLY the same code you posted here as in your test? Because IE11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox report `.sidebar` height: 50px when resizing, maximized as well as full screen (F11). No difference, only when the text `<p>` wraps, then it becomes higher (68px).

Comment: What browsers are you using? (@Taisho Mori and @Rishab Tyagi) Because with or without the 18% I see no change in height of `.sidebar`, stays 50px at all time (when not wrapping). Post pics of difference, please.

Comment: I just edited my question to add the full code on both html and css.

Comment: I am using chrome. I used the inspect tools on chrome and it does says that the size is the same, but the height of the sidebar shrinks a little bit.

Comment: Here are two pics - https://imgur.com/a/Th5IPIg

Comment: Like i already said  before, i have added a bottom margin on the first article, but at max browser it is aligned properly with the sidebar. Why would the height of the sidebar shrink a bit just because the browser gets minimized?

Comment: Update: i just realized that, the shrinking of the height happens when i shrink the height of the browser. Even when minimized, when i expand it to cover the entire screen, the height of the sidebar returns to the way it was. But then as i start shrinking the browser height, the sidebar height shrinks with it.

Comment: Sorry, but onmodified your (LAST) code does not reproduce the error. All my W10-x64 browsers (most recent), IE11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Palemoon do not show the error you encounter. Also, they all have the same layout when resized and don't stretch `<aside>` to 200%. See [image](https://i.postimg.cc/tJDH1CQk/so62261945.jpg). This is as far as I can go with the posted code...

Comment: Well, i am guessing you don't see the same error because the page you are seeing is not the same. Why aren't the elements in your code stretched to 200%? The height of the two articles is set to 100%, and the height of the sidebar to 200%, yet in your code, they small height.

Comment: I've added an answer to prove that I am using the exact code and to support my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is here just to show OP that I am using the exact code posted. It will be removed later....**

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


header {

background-color:lightgray;
height:150px;
color:black;
text-align:;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
font-size:50px;
font-family:OCR A Stf, monospace;


}

header a {

    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;


}

nav {

    background-color:darkblue;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;


}

nav a {

    text-decoration:none;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;

}



article {
    background-color:white;
    height:100%;
    padding:15px;
    overflow:;
    width:80%;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}


article h2 {

    padding-bottom:30px;
    color:black;

}




footer {

    background-color:lightgray;
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:15px;   
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;


}


.sidebar {

  padding:15px;
  width:18%;
  height:200%;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid lightgray;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float:right;


}


@media (max-width:700px) {

        .sidebar, .pics, .pics2 {

            width:100%;

        }
}
```

```html
<header> 
<a href="new-wc3.html">Cities of the world</a>
 </header>



<nav>

<a href="new york page.html">New York City</a>
<a href="#2">Los Angeles</a>


</nav>


<section style="background-color:#f1f1f1; padding:30px; overflow:hidden">



<aside class="sidebar">

<p>This should be a sidebar</p>

</aside>




<article class="pics">

 <h2>Please select a city.</h2>

</article>



<article class="pics2">

 <h2>Please select a city.</h2>

</article>


</section>




<footer>

<p>Copyright &copy; 2020, Cities of the World</p>

</footer>
```

Comment: I am confused. Why isn't the height in your code working? The code clearly says 100% for both articles and 200% for the sidebar, yet the webpage doesn't change. There must be some problem with your browser or something else. I don't understand.

Comment: @Taisho Mori It is my experience that it is hardly ever the browser's fault. And I checked 5 (as in five) browsers, all with the same result. So I would suggest you create a new document, copy the code you posted here and try again. Remember, you are the one experiencing a problem and I am not. Lateral thinking....

Comment: @Taisho Mori And... **I am confused. Why isn't the height in your code working?** It is not my code, it is YOUR code, I keep saying this all the time.

Comment: But that is not the page i am seeing? In my page, the two articles are 100% height, and the sidebar has 200% height, wheres in your page, the article and the sidebar do not have the height that is written in the CSS code. It clearly says 100%  for the article, yet the article element stays at low height. That is not my problem. My problem is that the sidebar height, which is correctly displayed as 200%, shrinks as i minimize the browser height. I have no idea why is your page not matching the code.

Comment: I did compare my code with the code you posted here, and it seem the same. I do not understand why is your result different. What is displayed does not match the code. That is not what happens when i run the code. I mean, it clearly states 100% height for the two articles, yet the articles don't have 100% height. In my page, they have. I don't understand why.

Comment: I just copied the code you have posted above in my editor, and the results are different. It's the same page as my previous one. The articles have a height of 100% as specified in the CSS, and the sidebar has a height of 200% as specified in the CSS.

Comment: I seriously have no idea why is the webpage produced by the code here does not display properly the height as specified by the CSS.

Comment: I mean, it literally says 200% for the sidebar, yet the page doesn't show that. There is a problem with this website, or i don't know.

Comment: You're kidding, right? Everything is at fault, except you and your code? Sorry, but I'm done looking at this.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. Can you not see that in your code, the CSS property for height is set at 200% for the sidebar, and 100% for each article, yet the actual webpage that is shown here is not the same height? The original question that i asked is completely different from the issue we are discussing right now. My issue was that, once the sidebar gets to 200% as set by the CSS, it shrinks once the browser is minimized. I don't understand why are you blaming the code, when you can clearly see that the CSS of the code says 200% but the page does not match that.

Comment: Sure I can see that, but your question was about a tiny difference in size when you resize the browser, not about why the `.sidebar` doesn't grow to 200%. You even posted an image showing that little difference and how it messes up the equal alignment of the articles. You made no mention whatsoever (in your request for help) as to why the `.sidebar` doesn't grow to 200%. The code you posted (which I am using) does not show the little difference, neither does it mess up the alignment. I'm not even looking at the 200% issue as you did not point it out being an issue.

Comment: And again, it is not my code. I took your code and posted is as a snippet without changing anything. Apart from the 200% issue, the code does not show the tiny misalignment when resizing the browser. Hence, the problem you have is not reproducible. It's not that I don't understand the code, I think you forgot what you asked help for in the first place. For as far as I can see from the image and the results I get looking at my browsers, you must be using different code.

Comment: Well, i didn't point it out, because it's not an issue for me. The height of my elements match the height set in the CSS. I am not having the issue that you're having. Obviously you can't see the height of the sidebar shrinking when the browser is minimized, since you sidebar is not even the right height.

Comment: I am not using a different code. I literally copied both codes that you have posted above in my text editor and the page was the same it was before. The two elements have the right height set by the CSS. You can't see my problem of the height shrinking a bit because your height is not 200% of the page. I think the problem might be that stackoverflow snippets can't have a larger page than the default one, and since my page has bigger height and has a scroll, the height doesn't work here. I don't know. I have no idea why is the height not working in the snippet.

Comment: Anyway, don't worry about it. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Taisho Mori, Well, lets agree to leave the issue 'hanging'. I will be removing my answer shortly, unless you are interested in my fully responsive 'flexbox' alternative, without issues. Responsive fonts, spacing and document layout. Works in all browsers (even IE11). Shows 2 articles with sidebar and a 3rd article underneath.